# Azure Easy Tables & Azure Storage Accounts - Load both at the same time

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin.forms, azure-storage-account

I am looking for a solution how to make loading from Azure Easy Tables and Azure Storage at the same time in Xamarin.Forms. I know how to load azure easy tables to ListView in Xamarin.Forms but I also need to load images from Azure Storage and display both in ListView.

Thank you for your time !

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code so we can help.

Comment: I have tried loading both and than bind them to ListView. The problem was I could not combine them togehter. In Azure Easy Tables I only store image names.